# Extract image from URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, uiimage, nsdata

The url is:

```
https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com
```

I want to get above image into to a UIImage. I tried this:

```
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com"];

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlString];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

But it seems this doesn't work. The url doesn't have an file extension like `.png` or `.jpg`. Is is possible to extract the image from this kind of URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, what you're going to want to do is `UIImagePNGRepresentation` in the case of this particular image (because the image you linked is actually `.png`) to basically convert the data to a workable image. If you are trying to use a `.jpg` image use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

```
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString]])];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Or, if you're as big of a fan on one-liners as I am, you can use this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com"]]])];
```